# Expression simplification with any algorithm concept

Tags: java, regex, algorithm, expression-trees, drools

I am having different expression in string format(In Java) as for example :

```
String expression = "IN G1 AND OUT G1 AND (IN G2 OR OUT G3)
```

Here G1 , G2 , G3 represents area and keywords are only IN , AND , OUT , OR , (, ) can be used.
I have to check that the expression is logically correct or not and want to simplify these type's of expressions.

Here meaning of expreesion is that a thing lies in G1 and it should be ouside G1(which is not possible logically) and it should lie in G2 or it should be outside G4.

Now I want a algorithm from which I will be able to detect that expression is logically incorrect as there is no possibility of thing to satisfy **IN G1 AND OUT G1** (such like cases).

The expression can be nested at any level. Please guide me any way how can I detect logical correctness of these types of expressions and will reduce an expression to some extend if it is not logical.

I know this is an little tricky algorithm  to implement but any help for this is well appreciated. Thanks In Advance

Comment: So, what's the problem? Have you even attempted anything?

Comment: Yes I have tried via concept of If Else and iteration in Java but that does'nt seems to be working for nested and nested conditions :(

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem - it's hard in general.

Comment: However, the last section of the wikipedia article linked by @OliCharlesworth does provide a number of useful links to practical algorithms.

Comment: Yes rici u are right this time :(